# What is the best way to pass data between routes using Provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, provider

I just started using the Provider package, and I've done basic data passing on the same screen(/ state).

But I'm having a problem **passing data from one screen(route) to another using Provider package**
I would appreciate it if someone can shed more light on this...

Comment: Put your provider above MaterialApp

Comment: Thanks for the response....You just saved a life

Answer (score 0):

```
    MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => Loader(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SplashBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TermsBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => InitialBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => HomeBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AboutusBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => EntryBlock()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AllEventBlock())
    ],
    child:  MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter',
   
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:
      
       Scaffold(
         
         body:SplashScreen()
          ),
     
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
    ));


 Try with multiple provider . You can use data anywhere in-app.
```